# onHover font colour not changing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an input box that when the user starts typing it will display a div with a list of possible clubs that they can select.

I'm just trying to add some styling to it at the moment and I'm having a problem with my .clubLink:hover class.

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    .clubList { display: none; width: 250px; margin-top: -5px; margin-left: -4px; border: 1px solid; }
    .clubLink { width: 240px; padding: 5px; }
    a { text-decoration: none; color: black; font-size: 10px; }
    a:hover { color: #FFFFFF; }
    .clubLink:hover { background-color: #0066FF; color: #FFFFFF; }  
</style>
```

**HTML/ColdFusion:**

```
<table width="450" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="content">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="content">Club Select</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content2">
        <td>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="content"><strong>Please Select a Club:</strong></td>
                    <td align="left"><input type="text" name="clubFilter" id="clubFilter" class="formItem"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" class="content">   
                        <div id="clubList" class="clubList">
                            <cfloop query="Variables.getClubs">
                                <div class="clubLink">
                                    <span class="clubName"><a href="passwordreset.cfm?cid=#clubID#">#clubName#</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </cfloop>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script>    

$('#clubFilter').bind("keyup", function() {
    var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var items = $(".clubName");

    items.parent().hide();

    items.filter(function () {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1;
    }).parent().show();

    $('#clubList').css("display", "block");
});

</script>
```

When I'm hovering over a club record div (clubLink class) in the filtered list the background colour changes but the font colour remains black.

The only time the font changes to white is when I actually hover the club name and the anchor style applies.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
.clubLink:hover { background-color: #0066FF; color: #FFFFFF; }  
.clubLink:hover a{color: #FFFFFF; }
```

Comment: Thanks - that sorted it. Will accept this as the answer in 8 minutes (when it allows)

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor should have a `display:block` value, to trigger when you hover on `.clubLink` element

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but why?

Comment: Because it will take space only as it contents(as is it an inline element). While having a display value, set to block, will take all the parent space

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the color of the `div` font, but the text color is given by `a` so it makes sense that it stays the same when hovering the div. What you'll  want to do is make `a` inherit the color of the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/sY4Gf/

```
 .clubList {
     display: none;
     width: 250px;
     margin-top: -5px;
     margin-left: -4px;
     border: 1px solid;
 }
 .clubLink {
     width: 240px;
     padding: 5px;
     color:red; /* for testing */
 }
 a {
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 10px;
     color:inherit;
 }
 .clubLink:hover {
     background-color: #0066FF;
     color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```